# "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in production webpack build

Tags: webpack

I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" while running production build of my application, built with webpack 4.20.2. Development build runs fine. Maybe someone has issued similar problem?

Here is my production config: https://gist.github.com/abm0/7a91914ceb8a7eb0dc220722a7c32407

and dev config: 
https://gist.github.com/abm0/6ce1e71d5c2396c93026524ac47f1463

Answer (score -1):

While in production mode, Webpack does some extra bundling optimisations. So, try using `modules: false` in your .babelrc, which tells Webpack to use CommonJS syntax `module.exports = {}`. Refer the discussed issue [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3974#issuecomment-278282755):

```
{
"presets": [
    ["env",
    {
        "useBuiltIns": true,
        "modules": false,
    }], "react", "stage-0"
],
"plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't help. Though I will use the link you provided to find more information, thanks.